# a3c continuous action probelm

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I want to implement reinforcement learning for a game which uses the mouse to move. This game only cares about x-axis of the mouse.

My first try is to make it discrete.  The game will have 3 actions. Two actions are used to move the mouse 30 pixels to left and right and one action for standing still. It worked but now I want to make it continuous.

What I have done is to make the neural network output mean and std. Exactly like this code https://github.com/stefanbo92/A3C-Continuous/blob/master/a3c.py. I even used this code on a second try. The width of the game is 480 so A_BOUND are [-240,240]. To make the problem always have a positive action, I added the predicted action to 240 then set the mouse position to the new one.

For example: If the action is 240 + -240, then the mouse x pos will be 0. The problem is that my neural network output only extremes from 240 to -240 consistently seconds after the start.

Comment: How large is your learning rate?

Comment: my learning rate is 0.0001

Comment: Does it get better if you reduce it?

Comment: I tried 1/5 of the previous one and I adjusted the weights and biases. Now extremes don't happen but my actor loves going positive so my mean is always positive. This might be because there is more reward in the positive, but it should try to get the reward of both and always goes positive and negative when necessary. The only time it goes negative is at the start then never go back. I have no idea why. – dark1sider 7 mins ago

Comment: Please [edit] the typo in your title, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your problem is because the output of your neural network is being squashed by an activation function.  This is a problem because there are very few values that results in a output that is not the max or min value.

[image: Hyperbolic tangent activation function]
Tanh activation

The above is the shape of the hyperbolic tangent activation function.  As you can see, the value is only non max/min if the input values are between -3 to 3, any values outside of that results in either the max or min values.

To overcome this, you must initialize your neural network with very small weights.  You can initialize the weights using random uniform values between -0.003 to 0.003.  Those are the values I use.  This way, initially, your neural network will output close to 0 values, and then the weights will be updated and the learning will be more stable.

To further correct for this error, you must put a small penalty for performing a large changes in state.

For example, penalty = (state * 0.01) ^ 2, where state = [-240, 240].

This way, your neural network will realize that theres a higher loss associated with large changes, so it will use it sparingly, and only when necessary.

Comment: Sorry for no replying soon, I was trying different things. I tried low weights and it worked but I didn't know how to do the penalty loss thing lets say this code for example github.com/stefanbo92/A3C-Continuous/blob/master/a3c.py self.a_loss = tf.reduce_mean(-self.exp_v)+(self.a_his * 0.01) ^ 2 is this right ? Or I put the penalty to the episodes rewards ??

Comment: you would have to do this: self.a_loss = tf.reduce_mean((-self.exp_v)+(self.a_his * 0.01) ^ 2).  Make sure the whole loss is in the reduce mean function.

Comment: Thank you so much, now my neural network doesn't go extreme. The only problem left is that it starts going from negative to positive but after a while, it never goes negative at all. There are rewards in both positive and negative but generally, there is more in positive that is why it stuck and never goes negative. I don't how to fix this. Is there any trick to force it to learn to go negative.

Comment: If the optimal action is to go positive, is there a reason why you want the mouse to go negative?

Comment: To get the maximum rewards the mouse need to go to negative even though there is more chance of reward being in positive. My input is 83 by 83 grayscale image. I have 3 convolution layers and 1 dense with 256 units. The mean changes very slightly when the frames change for example it stays at 0.454 to 0.46 for the next frame and std goes so low. It won't go negative with this behavior. I'm currently trying beta distribution.

Comment: I think this has something to do with the mapping of your states to action.  Try normalizing your states, that should make the difference between states bigger, and make the mapping easier.  To normalize, first simulate the process for at least 1000 time steps, then find the mean and standard deviation of the states.  Then, restart the simulation, but before feeding the states to your RL.  Subtract the mean from the states, and divide it by the standard deviation.

Comment: I really appreciate that you are really trying to help. The game I'm working with look like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EaIhz1dGbCc. If it hit the green plate I give it one reward if fall down it gets -1 reward and anything else gets 0 reward. The game seems to be normalized but I will try your idea. Action is just the x of the mouse. What do you think I should put as gamma, entropy beta and learning rate? Also what about activation functions in the conv and dense layers. Mine after 10000 episode chooses to stay in the right lane all the time mouse x will be consistently 0.4.

Comment: I personally use DDPG methods for my AC RL methods.  My learning rate for the actor s 0.0001 and my critic is 0.001.  I also use batch size annealing for convergence.  Basically, you increase batch size for gradient descent by a multiple (e.g. 5x) after each 100 episodes.  It works like annealing learning rate for learning, so it allows the system to converge.  For gamma and entropy beta, I personally use 0.95 for gamma (equivalent to about 20 steps look ahead).  For DDPG,I use OU noise, and not entropy.  But I'd make your system slowly damp out the noise as epsiodes goes on.

Comment: For the conv layers, I'm sorry but I'm not an expert in computer vision, it may be better to ask someone that works with conv nets to give you a more precise answer.  For my RL work, I use it to control large chemical processes and robotics.  So I have sensors in the field giving me direct measurements, instead of using computer vision to give me measurements.  The biggest problem I see is that your states are too similar to each other, and the inherent weakness of neural nets is that it approximates a solution, therefore, it wont pick up subtle differences.